# Barycentric Polynomail Interpolation, Evaluating the approximation/function

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose I have following Barycentric Form of a interpolating polynomial of a function f(x)

[image]

How would I evaluate 
$$f(0), f(1),f(2),f(3)?$$

Given 
$$x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1, x_2= 2, x_3=3$$

f(x) is not given.

Using the definition of Barycentric Form, I was able to get

$$f(0) = f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 6$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is f? Also, this is a rational function, not a polynomial

Comment: @YuriyS f is not given. What is given is that  x0 = 0, x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3

Comment: Presumably $f$ is a typo, and the problem is to evaluate $P(0)$, $P(1)$, etc. instead.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Don't see how I can evalulate that as well though, since we get divide by 0. Unless the rational form is re-arranged to a polynomial. But that defeats the purpose, if rearranged to monomial form.

Comment: Take limits, e.g. $$P(1) = \lim_{x \to 1} P(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{3/(x-1)}{(1/2)/(x-1)} = 6.$$